# How to pass conditions to NestJS typeorm repository find method from a variable?

Tags: mysql, find, nestjs, typeorm

I want to execute the following function in NestJs with typeorm.

```
public async getBooks(id: number, status) {
   let filter = {
      bookId: id 
   };

   if(status != 0) {
      filter['status'] = status;
   }

   return await this._bookRepository.find(filter);
}
```

_bookRepository is the repository for the Book entity and I`m using MySQL database. The function returns empty values and it returns values if I use JSON body of the filter variable instead of the variable.

What is the issue here?

Comment: I think you should nest theses filters in `where` field. Read the docs, bro https://typeorm.io/#/find-options

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database. The codes don't seem to have anything wrong.